# Master Master replication between RDS and database instance on EC2 Errno: 1032

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, amazon-rds, database-replication, master-master

I face this error many times with my replication

> Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows event on table
>   db_name.event; Can't find record in 'event', Error_code: 1032; handler
>   error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.000131,
>   end_log_pos 2869333

and I solved it by backup the database and restore it back to the another server then Restart the replication by CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE and MASTER_LOG_POS.

But I need to know the reason of that! why it happened?

Comment: This is one of the error for MySQL Replication when MASTER and SLAVE replica not in sync. The Reason for replication getting out of sync due to various reasons. But the common cause is particular table row or data not matched/missing on the slave while applying transaction received from MASTER. This transaction can be insert/update/delete type.

Comment: so i need to know why that happen as i configured it to be Master-Master replication so any data deleted,inserted or updated must be changed on both!

Comment: If you don't want to have this kind of problem, why don't use galera replication?